# IllegalBlockSizeException when trying to decrypt with keystore

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, keystore

I am trying to build a class to encrypt and decrypt a user custom class that I made. I want to encrypt all the fields of the user, and then store them as a string inside the user class, and then decrypt the fields and store them back in the user class.

I've encountered two problems. One is that I noticed that after I decode the byteArray to string and then encode it back, I get a block that is not the same size as it was(which was 16), so I am getting illegalblocksizeexception, but even when the block is a multiple of 16 I am getting badpaddingexception.

I tried not to convert it to string and work only in byteArray for testing but it still gives the same errors.

the code to the crypto class:

```
package com.plcoding.androidcrypto

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
class CryptoManager {

    private val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
        load(null)
    }

    private val encryptCipher get() = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
        init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey())
    }


    private fun getDecryptCipherForIv(iv: ByteArray): Cipher {
        return Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
            init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(), IvParameterSpec(iv))
        }
    }


    private fun getKey(): SecretKey {
            val existingKey = keyStore.getEntry("secret", null) as? KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
            return existingKey?.secretKey ?: createKey()
        }

        private fun createKey(): SecretKey {
            return KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM).apply {
                init(
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        "secret",
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                    )
                        .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
                        .build()
                )
            }.generateKey()
        }

        private fun encrypt(inputStream: ByteArray): String{
            val encryptedBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(inputStream)

            val size = encryptCipher.iv.size+encryptedBytes.size
            val stream = ByteArray(size)

            System.arraycopy(encryptCipher.iv,0,stream,0,encryptCipher.iv.size)
            System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes,0,stream,encryptCipher.iv.size,encryptedBytes.size)

            return  stream.decodeToString()


        }

    private fun decrypt(inputStream: ByteArray): String {
        val iv = ByteArray(encryptCipher.iv.size)
        val encryptedBytes = ByteArray(inputStream.size - iv.size)
        System.arraycopy(inputStream, 0, iv, 0, iv.size)
        System.arraycopy(inputStream, iv.size, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.size)

        return getDecryptCipherForIv(iv).doFinal(encryptedBytes).decodeToString()
    }


        fun encryptUser(user: User): User {
            val encryptedName = user.name?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { encrypt(it) }
            val encryptedApp= user.app?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { encrypt(it) }
            val encryptedPassword = user.password?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { encrypt(it) }
            val encryptedNotes = user.notes?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { encrypt(it) }

            return User(encryptedName,encryptedApp,encryptedPassword,encryptedNotes)
        }

        fun decryptUser(user: User?): User {
            val decryptedName = user?.name?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { decrypt(it) }
            val decryptedApp = user?.app?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { decrypt(it) }
            val decryptedPassword= user?.password?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { decrypt(it) }
            val decryptedNotes = user?.notes?.encodeToByteArray()?.let { decrypt(it) }

            return  User(decryptedName,decryptedApp,decryptedPassword,decryptedNotes)


        }

        companion object {
        private const val ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES
        private const val BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC
        private const val PADDING = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        private const val TRANSFORMATION = "$ALGORITHM/$BLOCK_MODE/$PADDING"
    }
   
 }
```

the user class:

```
class User(
    val name: String? = null,
    val app: String? = null,
    val password: String? = null,
    var notes: String? = null,
    val id: String? = null,
){
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you use `decodeToString` but encrypted data can not be decoded to a String because it is binary data. You have to encode it e.g. using Base64 to make it a (longer) String. Note that encrypting data field-by-field can cause security issues as an attacker can exchange the fields. Therefore it is better to convert the whole User object e.g. to a JSON String (or a different serialization format) and then encrypt the JSON String.

Comment: Besides the encoding issue, there is another bug: In `encrypt()`, every time `encryptCipher` is applied, the getter is invoked which reinitializes the cipher and automatically generates a new IV (even if this is not necessary, e.g. when determining the IV, the IV size, etc.). This causes the IV used in encryption and the concatenated IV to be different, causing decryption to fail. You need to modify your design so that only one initialization is performed per encryption.

Comment: I'd use the `key` as a field and simply instantiate and initiate the cipher with the encryption / decryption methods. You can then instantiate the crypto manager for a specific key. Ciphers are lightweight objects, there is no need to centralize their usage.